# Create dictionary of shortest distances grouped by their "group"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a data file containing a bunch of location coordinates with their "code" name and their "group" letters:

```
code, x,      y,    group,  n,  importance
x1, 4.5692, 2.747,    P,    1,    3
x2, 2.2551, 16.7944,  H,    2,    1
x3, 15.761, 15.1464,  R,    3,    4
x4, 15.6516, 5.1249,  C,    4,    5
x5, 6.0939, 9.8601,   S,    5,    2
...
```

I am trying to write a function that outputs dictionary(s) of locations with minimum distance to the input location(s):

```
def search(inputFile,LocationCode,radius):
   from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
   data = dict()
   with open(inputFile) as file:        
       next(file) 
       readin = file.readlines()
       for lines in readin:
           line = lines.strip('\n')
           (code, x, y, group,n,importance) = line.split(",")
           data[code] = x,y,group,n,importance   
   float_rad = float(radius)

   to_search = []
   for i in LocationCode:
       find = data.get(i)
       to_search.append(find)

   search_x = []
   search_y = []
   for j in range(len(to_search)):
       sx = float(to_search[j][0])
       sy = float(to_search[j][1])        
       search_x.append(sx)
       search_y.append(sy)
 
   search_coord = list(zip(search_x,search_y))

   search_result = []
   distance = []

   for k in range(len(search_coord)):
       result_in_loop = []
       for i in data:
           all_x = float(data[i][0])
           all_y = float(data[i][1])
        
           if ((all_x - search_coord[k][0])**2 + (all_y - search_coord[k][1])**2) < (float_rad**2):
               result_in_loop.append(data[i])

 # Here starts to find distance & minimum...        
       distance_in_loop = []
       for o in range(len(result_in_loop)):
           dx = float(result_in_loop[o][0])
           dy = float(result_in_loop[o][1])
           if dx != search_coord[k][0] or dy != search_coord[k][1]:
               distance_in_loop.append(sqrt((dx - search_coord[k][0])**2 + (dy - search_coord[k][1])**2))       
       distance.append(distance_in_loop)

   testing = []
   for check in range(len(distance)):
       lmin = min(distance[check])
       testing.append(lmin)
            
   search_result.append(result_in_loop)    
#Test_run  
search('sample.csv',["x26", "x52"],3.5)
```

Basically, in the function first reads in the `inputFile` and set it in form of dictionary with "code" as its keys.

Then dict.get() the associated values of the input `locationCode` using for loop then append them into `to_search` list.

Next get the `x` and `y` coordinate values from `to_search` and append them into list `search_x` and `search_y` then at last zip them into a list called `search_coord` (its format is something similar to this: `[(4.5692,2.747),(2.2551, 16.7944)]`)

Then it starts to search locations that are within the input `radius` with coordinates of the input `LocationCode` (which are in `search_coord`) being the centers, using firstly a for loop on `search_coord` then a nested loop on the original `data` dictionary that runs the calculation to find locations within the radius. The data locations that are within the radius will then put into `result_in_loop`.

Later I made it to calculate distances of locations from the central input coordinates, append to `distance_in_loop` then finally put lists of values to `distance` outside the `for k in range(len(search_coord))` loop which did return me a list such as `[[dist_1,dist_2,dist_3...],[dist_1,dist_2,dist_3...]]`.

But now I am not sure how to create dictionaries that find minimum distance in `distance` then use data's `group` to group the locations values and in forms of something such as this:

```
>>  [{'H': ('x7', 2.3034), 'R': ('x81', 0.7736), 'C': ('x99', 2.0607), 'S': ('x65', 1.556)}, {'P': ('x46', 2.4717), 'H': ('x22', 1.4374), 'R': ('x88', 2.5338), 'S': ('x30', 2.0482)}]
```

In the other words, trying to make the function return lists containing dictionaries in forms of:

```
{ "group" : ("code" , the_distance) }
```

And, already tried use `min()` on `distance` but is confused on how to make a relation to their `group` (to make `distance` values related to `group` and `x,y` values in the original `data` dictionary)...

Comment: Off-topic: Your input file is in CSV format so you should read it with the `csv` module in the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is relative simple code to solve your problem if you can pack the data from the file in a structure like:

`{'group_name':('item_name',x,y)}` -> with x,y as coordinates

Then you can use the following function:

```
def find_min_distances(coordinates,data_dict):
    dx,dy=coordinates
    result={}
    for k, v in data_dict.items():
        for i in v:
            d=((i[1]-dx)**2+(i[2]-dy)**2)**0.5
            print(d,i[0],k) # just to control the result print can be removed later on!
            if k in result:
                if result[k][1]>d: # >= may make also sense depending what you want
                    result[k]=(i[0],d)
            else:
                result[k]=(i[0],d)
    return result
```

I tested with:

```
b={'H':[('x2',3.4,8.9),('x3',4.9,18.9)],'B':[('x4',1.4,1.9),('x5',14.9,8.9)],'C':[('x6',1.4,8.9),('x7',4.9,18.9)]}
print(find_min_distances((1,2),b))
```

Delivering:

```
{'C': ('x6', 6.911584478250989), 'B': ('x4', 0.41231056256176596), 'H': ('x2', 7.305477397131552)}
```